# "Until death" or "until dead"?

Tags: till-until

I do wonder what is correct "until dead" or "until death". We have been arguing about this for a few hours. For me, it's more natural to say "Until dead" but I'm not sure, if I'm right or not. What is correct and what is not?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you going to hang someone by the neck until dead, or are you going to make regular payments until death?  More context would make your question clearer and make it possible to answer.

Comment: From Google Books - [hanged by the neck until **dead**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hanged+by+the+neck+until+dead%22):6,380 results, [hanged by the neck until **death**](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22hanged+by+the+neck+until+death%22),100 results. Draw your own conclusions.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Not quite the same context, but *until death do us part* has a long history.

Comment: @bib: I guess it just depends on context - which OP has neglected to provide.

Comment: @bib until death do us part, death is a subject of a dependent clause. Not an object of a preposition *until*.

Comment: there's no context, so assume, it's the name.

Comment: What kind of name? A computer game?

Comment: Both phrases occur in ritual utterances; _until dead_ is for executions. _Until death_, on the other hand, tends to occur in the phrase _until death do us part_, which is EME for 'until death parts us_ and is a part of many Christian marriage oaths.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a bit gruesome, but if you strangle somebody:

> *Until dead* means untile *he/she* is dead.

A subject and the verb *be* in a dependence clause are omitted.

> Until death means until his/her death occurs.

Here, [death](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/death) means:

> the end of life : *the time when someone or something dies*.

I don't see any reason why either of them is wrong.

Comment: You strangle someone *until dead*. But you strangle them *to death*. The choice is idiomatically driven.

Comment: Either way it is not a nice thing to do!